# Python How to check if data in list

Tags: python, list

I have a code:

```
dates = []

dates.append(['imie', 'nazwisko'])
dates.append(['test', 'test2'])
```

How can check if "imie" and "nazwisko" is in dates?

if 'imie' and 'nazwisko' in dates - not work

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to check that both of them are present in `dates`?

Comment: You can use `sets` and their operators: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 3):

Using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> dates = []
>>> dates.append(['imie', 'nazwisko'])
>>> dates.append(['test', 'test2'])
>>> any(('imie' in d and 'nazwisko' in d) for d in dates)
True
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) as suggested by Jon Clements:

```
>>> any({'imie', 'nazwisko'}.issubset(d) for d in dates)
True
```

Comment: @JonClements, Thank you for comment. I added it to the answer according to you.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're appending lists to dates instead of the strings, so:

```
for i in dates:
    if 'imie' in i or 'nazwisko' in i:
        return True
return False
```